# Non-existent submodule mentioned in git error

Tags: git, git-submodules

Git is telling me I can't add some files to the index because they are in a submodule.  I think it's true that these files were once in a submodule, but I can't find any indication that they still are in a submodule.  If I grep for .gitmodules, I find nothing.  How can I eliminate this phantom submodule so I can add the files to my index?

```
ryan@ryan-HP-ProBook-4530s:/opt/staging/my.domain.com/public/profiles/mei_main$ ls
civicrm_starter.sql  mei_main.info  mei_main.install  mei_main.profile  modules  themes
ryan@ryan-HP-ProBook-4530s:/opt/staging/my.domain.com/public/profiles/mei_main$ git add themes
fatal: Path 'profiles/mei_main/themes' is in submodule 'profiles/mei_main'
ryan@ryan-HP-ProBook-4530s:/opt/staging/my.domain.com/public/profiles/mei_main$ ls -la
total 4704
drwxr-xr-x 4  48 502    4096 Aug 19 11:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 6  48 502    4096 Aug 19 11:49 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 503 502 4786089 Apr 29 13:43 civicrm_starter.sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1  48 502    2985 Jun  4 02:20 mei_main.info
-rwxr-xr-x 1  48 502     579 Jun  4 02:20 mei_main.install
-rwxr-xr-x 1  48 502     736 Jun  4 02:20 mei_main.profile
drwxr-xr-x 4  48 502    4096 Aug 26 17:26 modules
drwxr-xr-x 4  48 502    4096 Aug 16 10:23 themes
ryan@ryan-HP-ProBook-4530s:/opt/staging/my.domain.com/public/profiles/mei_main$ cd ../../
ryan@ryan-HP-ProBook-4530s:/opt/staging/my.domain.com/public$ grep path .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //'
grep: .gitmodules: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try `find -name .git`, I'm betting you've got a nested repo, i.e. a submodule.  The `.gitmodules` file is just default values for the  `git submodule` command, itself just assistance in schlepping nested repos around.

Comment: I tried find -name .git.  It found only my main .git repo.

Comment: Does `git ls-tree --full-tree HEAD|grep '^160000 commit'` get any hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the directory visible to git by renaming it...

mv profiles profiles2

After renaming it, git could see it, and I could add it to the repo...

git add profiles2

And then...

git mv profiles2 profiles

When pulling the changes down to the staging site, git aborted, complaining that it couldn't overwrite untracked files.  So, I had to rename the dir on staging...

mv profiles profiles2

Then, I could pull...

git pull

Lastly, move the old untracked profiles directory somewhere for safe keeping...

mv profiles2 ~

Answer (score 1):

If the `.gitmodules` file is missing, take a look inside `.git/config`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule) for more info on how to clean everything out.

Comment: There is no mention of submodules in .git/config, nor is there any modules directory in .git.

Comment: So, at the moment, I have this directory that I can't add to git, because git thinks it's a submodule.  Yet there is no file anywhere that declares that it is a submodule.  If I do git add for this directory, git does not complain.  But if I then do git status, the directory is not staged for commit -- it isn't mentioned anywhere.  I have also confirmed that the path is not in my .gitignore file.